# UI design for a mobile website

Tags: user-interface, mobile-website

Iam developing a site in which there are many reports to be generated. For that I have many forms, input controls to be displayed on the screen. Is there a specific way of designing form controls for a mobile web. Because when I see it in mobile they appear very small. Any Guide lines please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great article on the YUI blog: [Challenges of Interface Design for Mobile Devices](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/10/02/challenges-of-interface-design-for-mobile-devices/). It also references all the user interface guidelines from most of the manufacturers.

---

ACCESS / Palm OS

- [ACCESS | Palm OS Application Design](http://www.access-company.com/developers/documents/docs/ui/UI_Design.html)
- [Zen of Palm (PDF)](http://www.access-company.com/developers/documents/docs/zenofpalm.pdf)

Apple iPhone/iOs

- [Apple Mobile Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)

BlackBerry

- [Optimizing Content for the BlackBerry Browser (PDF)](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/7979/1181821/832210/Optimizing_Content_for_the_BlackBerry_Browser.pdf?nodeid=1206500&vernum=0)

Nokia

- [Nokia Web Design Guide](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/)

Microsoft Mobile Internet Explorer

- [Microsoft | Mobile Web Development](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286514.aspx)

Motorola

- [Motorola Developer Guides](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/developerguides/)

---

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a viewport meta issue. Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">
```